# Management of transparency of layer using QGIS Server and mapproxy

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, qgis-server, mapproxy

I have problems using mapproxy with QGIS-server via openlayers (mapproxy-1.6.0, qgis-server 2 and openlayers-2.13.1).

I have a layer in which i defined the background of the polygon with transparency.

When I asked directly  qgis-server via openlayers, I get the png wanted (png background is entirely transparent and the transparency of the background is what i need).

When I pass through maproxy, the image background is transparent but not the background of the polygons (the setting of the mapproxy may be ok because I get a transparent png image).
What's weird is when I set the background of a polygon with less than 50% transparency in QGIS, through mapproxy the background of the polygon is completely opaque and when I put a transparency equal to or greater than 50%, the background of polygons is completely transparent.

Exemple directly from qgis-server : [image]

Exemple via mapproxy : [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In source or cache settings, add **paletted:false** to force PNG to 24 bits not 8bits

http://mapproxy.org/docs/1.6.0/confi...image-paletted

```
globals:
    picture:
        paletted: false
```

or

```
cache:
    mycache:
        ...
        picture:
            paletted: false
```

For more precision, the pixels of a PNG8 (8bit) have an alpha channel but they are either completely opaque or completely transparent. For PNG24 the pixels can have 256 levels of transparency.
http://www.sitepoint.com/png8-the-clear-winner/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portabl...rency_of_image "